# Getting error when running npm install after update node version to 14

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, node-sass

I have updated my node version and npm version. The versions are as follows

> node is 14.15.4
> npm is 8.3.0

My package.json has these things

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "sshpk": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "AfterBuild": [
      "install"
    ]
  }
```

Now when I run npm-install I get this error

[image]

When I check the log I get this

```
> 3078 verbose stack Error: spawn bash ENOENT 3078 verbose stack     at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
> 3078 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
> 3078 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) 3079 verbose pkgid
> node-sass@4.14.1 3080 verbose cwd
> D:\TeamCityBuildAgent2\work\b86263cf69dd6b40\Web 3081 verbose
> Windows_NT 6.3.9600 3082 verbose argv "C:\\Program
> Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
> "C:\\Users\\chaudhrymohsin.ali\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
> "install" 3083 verbose node v14.15.5 3084 verbose npm  v8.3.0 3085
> error code ENOENT 3086 error syscall spawn bash 3087 error path
> D:\TeamCityBuildAgent2\work\b86263cf69dd6b40\Web\node_modules\node-sass
> 3088 error errno -4058 3089 error enoent spawn bash ENOENT 3090 error
> enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 3090
> error enoent 3091 verbose exit -4058 3092 timing npm Completed in
> 32047ms 3093 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1652985500999 3094
> verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1652985531192 3095 verbose
> unfinished npm timer build 1652985531194 3096 verbose unfinished npm
> timer build:deps 1652985531194 3097 verbose unfinished npm timer
> build:run:install 1652985531461 3098 verbose unfinished npm timer
> build:run:install:node_modules/node-sass 1652985531462 3099 verbose
> code -4058
```

Anyone knows what should be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ***sass*** package instead of ***node-sass***

```
npm uninstall node-sass --save
npm install sass --save
```